# Is html5 robust enough for business applications?

Tags: html

Like, can I write a business strength application in HTML5 that mimics our current system that contains many highly interactive grids, custom trees and so on.

We have a good working system written in C# WinForms with parts done in WPF and have recently embarked on writing a custom app for the iPad that communicates through WCF with our main server hosts.  We now have a very fast custom grid written in C# that compiles to Objective C through MonoTouch and also a cool interactive pie chart.

Now my boss wishes to build a version for Android and I am thinking if we shouldn't really be spending time creating a single HTML5 app that can run on both iPad and Android equivalents.

Thing is - take a grid - my grid on the iPad is fast (re-usable cells etc) - how would I create a grid from a 'dataset' type source in html5?  Do I really have to go down creating lots of  tags and then submitting them to the browser?  Are third party widgets like jqwidgets the answer??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit anecdotal, but my experience has been that HTML5/JavaScript are just not fast enough on mobile devices yet (in 2012) particularly if you are displaying lots of data, especially and you want fast response times with interactive features. Give it another year, and I wouldn't be surprised if this statement becomes outdated as mobile devices continue to evolve.

Mobile web development certainly has its uses currently, e.g., if you want to target the most devices with a single codebase; if you don't have enough development resources and are willing to settle for a non-native experience; if you don't have experience in the languages required for native development, etc.

Given that you already have done the work for the iPhone app, my humble opinion is that it's probably better to move forward with a native Android application -- you will get a much more responsive application for about the same amount of work at this point.

> how would I create a grid from a 'dataset' type source in html5?

Depending on what the grid contains, you can do it with plain old HTML tables or with a combination of other elements styled with CSS. There are really many more considerations though-- e.g., does it need to work on small screens (e.g., phones) or just larger screens (tablets). Often, you can't really fit a whole grid on a small screen, so you end up with UIs that aren't really grids anymore. You can take a look at a mobile JavaScript framework such as [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) to see how they've done it and maybe even consider using the framework for use in your own application.

Comment: It's not just the time and cost of getting the Android version out now, it's the ongoing support costs of having two code bases to update for every change. It's very much a trade-off, Native gives higher quality and performance at some costs - are the benefits worth it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and suggestions - the grid query really is about the principle that I have with say a large dataset with data in memory.  I wish to show this data in a grid.  The iPad calls back with events telling me it wants to show say rows 30 till 60 so I simply return the data it is asking for for those rows.  So there is no single large rendered <table ...> text being fed to the browser.  This is a very nice way of coding and thinking....   Again, how would I show this data in html5?

Comment: @djna - don't forget that my iPad grid (as described above) asks for the data it wants to show which I think is a fab programming model.  How would this work in html5?

Comment: @djna That's a very important point that I neglected to think of (+1).

Comment: @Marcel, If you only wish to show thirty rows at a time, one method is to render a <table> with 30 rows (<tr>) of data in it in it. You can have buttons that say "Prev" or "Next" with JavaScript event handlers that replace the data in the table when the buttons are clicked. You could load all of the data into memory (a JavaScript object in this case) and only display 30 at a time, or you could make Ajax calls to your server to get 30 rows at a time.

Comment: The incremental fetching of data is very usual in HTML5 apps. Fetching data with an Ajax call is easy, updating the existing widget is often just a single "here's your new data" call, an interesting bit comes in shall we pre-fetch some data or wait for the user to request it. All possible in JavaScript. the fundamental mindset is that the server merely delivers data, the html is largely constructed by JavaScript in the client.

Answer (score 0):

The various JavaScript frameworks (eg. JQuery and Dojo) have mobile device-specific widgets of  quite high quality. Have a look at http://dojotoolkit.org/features/mobile and http://jquerymobile.com/

How close do these get to native apps developed in ObjectiveC and Java? Not perfect but maybe good enough. You can also use a combination of native and HTML in the same app, some pages native some HTML. I'm doing that kind of thing with IBM's Worklight, but then I would, I work for IBM ;-) Irrespective of specific products I do see folks taking that approach.

In addition to portability, anoyther of the benefits of having much of the app in HTML  is that updated versions can be delivered without going via an app-store - this increases agility of functional delivery.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I certainly will have a look at the sites you recommend.

Answer (score 0):

As evidence, I'd say that a lot of Windows 8's apps are just wrapped JS/CSS/HTML, with a few APIs which Microsoft supplies to allow access to hardware/the filesystem.

I wouldn't think that they've gone so far as to make Excel 2013 JS-based...
...however, with that said, they have gone so far as to allow developers to extend their programs with applet views of the data -- those applets are all going to be built on "html5" (again with an MS-Office JS API).

It's not an easy road to go down -- people look to jQuery to be their saviour for these types of things.
This is exactly where jQuery would not be what you wanted, if you were looking to hack together a solution.
For example:

```
$(".table_cell").click(function () { alert(/*whatever*/); });
```

People think that jQuery is assigning a delegator to listen to any click on any element containing `class="table_cell"`.

That's really not what it's doing.
It's looping through each one, and attaching an event-listener to each one, directly.
It's these little things that people miss -- people like Twitter, who didn't bother caching references to elements, because jQuery is so easy to hack things together with.
So then you have JS touching (or acting on) dozens or hundreds of individual elements, at all times.

That's not good for anyone.

jQuery isn't bad at all -- it's quite helpful, as a low-level construct to help skirt around browser differences.
Some of its plugins are also all right.
I can't guarantee that they're all high-performing answers to all things.
But some of the plugin-creators understand how to maintain a responsive and well-performing program.

Which ones are right for your exact needs?  Who knows, other than you.

Will they perform perfectly, and quickly?
That depends on a lot of different things, of course.

Coming from C#, you might do to look at something like **AngularJS**.
Angular, itself, uses an internal version of jQuery, to tackle some of the low-level stuff that jQuery has made a solved-problem.
But it allows for data-binding, and pretty simple view templating.
**Hammer.js** is also a very decent gesture-tracking library.

From there, though, I'd suggest building your own framework, if you want it done the way that you want it to be done.
Nobody knows what your needs are but you, and trying to stuff things into a shoebox, because it's available, isn't always the solution, regardless of what various companies may think...

You can leave most of the node-work to Angular, you can leave the gesture-sensing to Hammer, you can pull out some other basics from jQuery-lite (the no-frills jQ installed inside of Angular, if you don't have jQ on your site), or jQ, itself...

But they're just tools and not answers.

The web can be very responsive if you cache references to elements, rather than querying for them over and over, delegate events, do large structure-changes off-DOM (on cloned-nodes, if necessary), and don't try to treat JS as a traditional inheritance-heavy language, and you remain mindful of how and when to use AJAX (number/frequency of calls versus size of data -- favour fewer calls).

Comment: Thanks Norguard for your suggestions - I will read up on all of these - it certainly gives food for (even more) thoughts...